# "Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.google.firebase.database.provider"

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to develop an application that utilizes Firebase and uploads and retreives photos + a text name from it.

I get that error when trying to take a photo, the application uses the native phone's camera.

My Manifest.xml file currently looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.Camera"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".EditImage"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ImageActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".display_image" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
</application>
```

And the provider_path like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And my code for taking a picture looks like this:

```
 public void captureImage(View view) {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
            File imageFile = null;

            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(imageFile!=null){

                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        }

    }
```

And here is the "getImageFile()" function

```
private File getImageFile()throws IOException {

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageName = "jpg_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);

        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;

    }
```

The issue here is when clicking the button that calls "captureImage()" I get thrown the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.camera.camerapsi, PID: 26813
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27582)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27582) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.google.firebase.database.provider
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:606)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
        at com.camera.camerapsi.MainActivity.captureImage(MainActivity.java:198)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27582) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I have no idea as to why my code doesn't work, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `get that error when trying to take a photo, ` Well nothing to do with fotos. Just calling getUriForFile() does it.

Comment: @blackapps Hey thanks for the reply, even so it doesn't tell me why it simply crashes throwing that exception.

Comment: If you catch that exception your app will not crash.

Comment: But the problem is that provider. Where does it come from?

Comment: Hey @blackapps, added the try/catch thanks for remembering. The provider is from Firebase "com.google.firebase.database.provider"

Comment: `imageFile = getImageFile();`. Nobody knows what that function does. So you could at least tell the value of imageFile.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Yes the provider is from firebase. I had seen that. But the provider is unknown.  Where does that come from? What does it have to do with your app? With your application id? Arent you surprised?

Comment: Image file outputs to "./storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.camera.camerapsi/files/DCIM/jpg_(nameofpicture)" I have edited the post. I don't know why that provider appears sinse I'm only getting now at the completion of my program. I assume it has something to do with Firebase operations @blackapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very case specific,  the following line `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFile);` is the problem. In this case "BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID" gets Firebase's ID instead of the application's it self.

The fix is the following: `"com.yourpackagehere.yourpackage" + ".provider", imageFile);` sinse Android Studio, maybe in conflict with a library from Firebase, doesn't manage to use its own BuildConfig

Hope this helps people with a problem like mine in the future!

Comment: Even I am facing a similar problem. Whenever I display *BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID* as a toast, it displays **com.google.firebase**. Can you clarify the reason?

Comment: I honestly don't know but I think it has to do with the way Android Studio and Firebase handle "BuildConfig". Maybe it's a tag conflict, I don't know. But my solution worked for my situation